# Golang Non-Blocking Buffer

Tags: go, concurrency, nonblocking

Synchronous Example:

```
type job struct {
    Id int
    Message string
}

for {
    // getJob() blocks until job is received
    job := getJob()
    doSomethingWithJob(job)
}
```

I wish to process jobs as they come in from `getJob` with `doSomethingWithJob`. e.g. getJob could be a payload received from a MessagingQueue such as RabbitMQ/Beanstalkd or handling a HTTP Request.

I don't want to block `getJob` whilst I am `doSomethingWithJob` & vice versa. I do however want to control / buffer the number of jobs so that I don't overload the system. e.g. max concurrency of 5.

The concept of go routines confuse me at the moment, so any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated to assist me learn.

**Update**: Thanks @JimB for your help. Why is worker 5 always picking up the job?

```
jobCh := make(chan *job)

// Max 5 Workers
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {

    go func() {

        for job := range jobCh {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(rand.Intn(3)))
            log.Println(i, string(job.Message))
        }
    }()
}

for {
    job, err := getJob()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Closing Channel")
        close(jobCh)
        break
    }

    jobCh <- job
}

log.Println("Complete")
```

Example output

```
2016/06/09 22:19:57 5 {"id":10692,"name":"Test Message"}
2016/06/09 22:19:57 5 {"id":10687,"name":"Test Message"}
2016/06/09 22:19:57 5 {"id":10699,"name":"Test Message"}
2016/06/09 22:19:57 5 {"id":10701,"name":"Test Message"}
2016/06/09 22:19:57 5 {"id":10703,"name":"Test Message"}
2016/06/09 22:19:57 5 {"id":10704,"name":"Test Message"}
```

Comment: it is not 5th worker, every worker got  i=5. It should be `go func(i int){ ... }(i)` https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start 5 goroutines reading from a channel to call `doSomethingWithJob`. That way there's never more than 5 jobs being processed concurrently.

```
jobCh := make(chan *job)

// start 5 workers to process jobs
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    go func() {
        for job := range jobCh {
            doSomethingWithJob(job)
        }
    }()
}

// send jobs to workers as fast as we can
for {
    jobCh <- getJob()
}
```

Comment: Wow... I have been looking at this all backwards and overcomplicating!

Comment: I have tried method above. And it works, however it looks like only worker 5 is picking up the job. See update in question.

Comment: @Gravy: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines. Every goroutine is using the same `i` variable, and the last value of i was `5` .